# Class and Method level generic type constraints interaction

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Consider the following class:

```
public class DerivedClassPool<TBase> where TBase : class
{
    public TBase Get(Type componentType)
    {
        // Not important, but you get the idea
        return Activator.CreateInstance(componentType) as TBase;
    }

    public TDerived SomeMethod<TDerived>() where TDerived : TBase
    {
        return Get(typeof(TBase)) as TDerived;
    }
}
```

Note that I've restricted the `TBase` generic class argument to be a class: `where TBase : class`
I've also restricted the `TDerived` generic method argument to be `TBase` or something derived from that: `where TDerived : TBase`.

I get an error on the `as TDerived` line:

> The type parameter 'TDerived' cannot be used with the 'as' operator because it does not have a class type constraint nor a 'class' constraint

I understand that to prevent the error I need to add the constraint `class`, so I'd get:

```
where TDerived : class, TBase
```

**Why do I have to do this when `TBase` is already constrained to be a class and `TDerived` is constrained to be a `TBase` or derived from it?**

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8002148/c-sharp-generics-contraints-propagation.  Eric lays it out there.

Comment: @Jason, I think it read better with the 'but'.

Comment: @Joey: Fair enough. I just hate when sentences start with `but`, even though using conjuncts to begin sentences is considered correct these days. I blame my high school English teacher. He was a stickler for classic English conventions.

Comment: The but sentence started with "I understand...", but had a code block in it. (I had used an in-line but with a line break in the middle it didn't look right)

Comment: I considered it as a single sentence, i.e. "I understand that to prevent the error I need to add the constraint class so I'd get foo, but why...". Anyway, it's not worth worrying about, especially as the question has been answered :D

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Ya, I see that now. I get carried away sometimes. Just call me OCD when it comes to grammar.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

UPDATE: This question was [the subject of my blog on September 19th, 2011](http://ericlippert.com/2011/09/19/inheritance-and-representation/). Thanks for the great question!

---

> Why do i have to do this when TBase is already constrained to be a class and TDerived is constrained to be a TBase or derived from it?

Because a value type can be derived from a reference type. `int` is derived from reference types `object` and `System.ValueType` and implements a number of interfaces. That doesn't make `int` a reference type.

It is perfectly legal for you to call `SomeMethod<int>` on an instance of `DerivedClassPool<object>` because int is derived from object.

Now, there *are* cases where your criticism would be warranted. One can construct situations in which two type parameters are related in such a way that both of them logically can only be reference types, but only one of them is classified by the language as "known to be of reference type".

As an exercise to the reader: can you find one? It might be necessary to carefully read section 10.1.5 of the specification for a precise definition of "known to be a reference type".

Comment: Is it possible to create our own value types that are derived from reference types (in C#)?

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett Why is that relevant?

Comment: @OskarKjellin: It isn't, i'm just curious. :)

Comment: @GeorgeDuckett: Of course. "struct S {}" There, done. That is a value type that I created that is derived from a reference type. In fact, it is derived from *two* reference types.

Comment: (Yes, from ValueType and object). An odd feeling came to me when reading your section: I found the reverse, apparently there's a type that's neither a value type nor a reference type. Semantically I understand that Pointers are neither, but it just feels kinda weird.

Comment: @Abel: correct. Pointers behave like references, in that they refer to storage locations. And they behave like values in that they are basically integers that you can do integer math on. The key fact though is pointer types are not derived from object and not convertible to object. Only types convertible to object may be used as generic type arguments.

Comment: @EricLippert: lol, point taken. My original question was pretty stupid; One of those 4:55pm moments I guess! :)

Answer (score 2):

Because `TBase` could be an interface and therefore `TDerived` could be a value type.

Comment: you sure about that?  http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx: `The type argument must be a reference type; this applies also to any class, interface, delegate, or array type.`

Comment: Did not know about that. Tricky that `class` means "value type" in this case

Comment: @OskarKjellin: "class" means "any reference type". "struct" means "any non-nullable value type".

Comment: @EricLippert Oops, I mistyped. Wrong way around